# Files in Desktop folder not showing on Desktop

Tags: files, directory

**Files in Desktop folder not showing on Desktop**
I have a number of documents and other stuff in the Desktop, but they are not visible on the Desktop, but visible on the File explorer, I have a Double Screen.
Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Install tweaks `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`. Then open Tweaks and go to Desktop and enable Icons.

Comment: it s already on

Comment: Add when i right click on the desktop I can just change background and Display settings and settings

Comment: At your login screen, which environment have you selected?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: What is the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: The same happens here - but only from time to time. My session type is X11, I am using Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue when creating folders. My usual fix is just to restart Ubuntu and everything should start showing up again on the Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

i am using ubuntu 22.04 and had similar issue.i just opened gnome-extensions(Extensions) and enabled Desktop Icons NG.

if you didnt install this extension you can add it with this command:

sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Icons were not showing on desktop
When i right click there is only three options 'change background', 'display settings' and 'settings'
And when you click one of them nothing happens, you can't access the settings
I did this to get back the icons:
`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng`
The icons are back however i couldn't open the settings even when i try to
So i did:
`sudo apt install gnome-control-center`